# Bioconductor, how to retrieve the genes from a GEO gene expression dataset?

Tags: r, bioconductor

I'm quite new to Bioconductor and GEO.

Here's my task: I've to develop a simple R script able to read a gene expression dataset on GEO and extract the genes related to it. But... I don't know the command to extract the gene list.

The GEO dataset I want to analyze is [GSE59867](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo/query/acc.cgi?acc=GSE59867).

Here's my R code:

```
options(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

library(oligo)
library(GEOquery)
source("https://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
biocLite("affyio")
library("affyio")

getGEOSuppFiles("GSE59867")
list.files("GSE59867")

untar("GSE59867/GSE59867_RAW.tar", exdir = "GSE59867/CEL")
list.files("GSE59867/CEL")

celfiles <- list.files("GSE59867", full = TRUE)
rawData <- read.celfiles(celfiles)
```

Now I have the `rawData` containing the gene expressions.

**How can I extract the list of genes associated to rawData at this point?**

Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at the `pd.hugene.1.0.st.v1` package. That contains the annotations for that microarray.